# Rails Active Admin css conflicting with Twitter Bootstrap css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I'm somewhat new to the Rails asset pipeline so I might be doing something wrong. I'm trying to use Active Admin for my backend and twitter bootstrap css for my front end application.

I added the bootstrap.css to **/app/assets/stylesheets** then also added:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

to application.css - then I did a precompile of the assets locally

It seems to work fine but some of the styling isn't coming through exactly and I think it's because active admin's css is overriding it.

My understanding is that the application compiles the css assets into the application css public asset and the application uses that file when running.

I need to somehow separate the two and make it use **twitter bootstrap css** as the main css on the front end and maybe tell it not to use **active admin's css** files on the front end.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why doesn't ActiveAdmin just change their class files to use a prefix like `_active-admin-` so they don't conflict with anything else? The way C libraries do. I think this is a bug in ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you watched the RailsCasts video on using ActiveAdmin? In the video, Ryan shows you how to prevent the ActiveAdmin CSS from stepping on your main app CSS.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Moving info from Video into answer

In the application.css you remove:

```
*= require_tree .
```

For rails 4, [Jiten K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304681/activeadmin-overides-my-css) suggests adding this to `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.css']
```

However one of the comments on that SO answer says this is not needed. I have not needed it so far.

Comment: MattSlay is correct ... Ryan's RailsCast (#284) will show you how to get around this (it's all because of the "require_tree ." in application.css). Removing/editing that will resolve the CSS issue.

Comment: This method works fine for me in development mode, but in production I have a problem when run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`: in my case, the css files finish mixed and bootstrap.css is overwritten by ActiveaAdmin. Any idea?. Thanks!

Comment: but but but `require_tree .` is the magic that lets all your CSS files get magically smooshed into one by Rails... this answer is overkill and should be un-accepted

Answer (score 131):

I had the same problem, and was able to fix it by moving

```
app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
```

to

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
```

The active admin assets **should** be in `vendor/` as mentioned in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization):

*"Vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks."*

Comment: It works fine when running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?. In my case, the css files finish mixed and bootstrap.css is overwritten by activeadmin. Any idea?.

Comment: And do the same for `active_admin.js`. Move it to `vendor/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`

Comment: Someone should submit a PR to fix this upstream.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Why load up a bunch of extra css outside of the /admin namespace if you don't need to (even if it doesn't conflict)? Only slows down page load time for average user.

Comment: It solved the problem for me too, for .scss and .js files, so it is still valid for rails 5.+

Comment: Had the same problem with custom CSS I wanted to add. This solution worked for me.

Comment: after I moved,  I got this error ' The asset "active_admin.css" is not present in the asset pipeline. '

Answer (score 12):

For me changing `application.css` to following solves the problem:

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= stub "active_admin"
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me, thanks. I haven't been able to figure out exactly what `stub` does, would you mind giving me a quick hint?

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working for me I have spent hours on resolving but endup on your fix

Comment: Can you please explain what does this *=stub "active_admin" does?