# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown broken after assets precompile

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, activeadmin

After `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` the [dropdown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) becomes unresponsive in development environment. Nothing happens on clicking the button. However removing everything from `public/assets` starts working. Also it works perfectly in production mode (`rails s -e production`)

The application uses [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) and [active admin](http://activeadmin.info/). Looks like something getting [conflicted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10180418/517483).

Note here it works fine in staging on Heroku

Here is a snap of generated html

```
<li id="organization-selector" class="dropdown">
    <a href="/" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#organization-selector" class="dropdown-toggle">
      RedKivi
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/organizations/1">RedKivi</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/organizations/2">BoTree</a>
      </li>                  
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="/organizations/new">New organization</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss**

```
...
....
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui.slider
 *= require_tree .
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.slider
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

What are practices to precompiling assets ?

Answer (score 3):

**Simply clean your assets folder:**

```
rake assets:clean:all
```

---

**Why does this happen?**

Bootstrap's Dropdown breaks on development only because, your assets are being loaded twice. Once in the "precompiled" form and the second because of your development environment. This causes a conflict and the dropdown doesn't work anymore.

That's why it works on Heroku/Production normally, because only the precompiled assets are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As I learn that normally you do not need to precompile assets locally. It is generally done in staging and production.

Actually in staging on Heroku, we are getting `ActionView::Template::Error (active_admin.css isn't precompiled)` [error](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/483). So we precompiles assets locally, pushed to remote repo before deployment to Heroku to fix it. This was the workaround and the cause of the problem.

The solution is given [this link](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Heroku-Cedar-deployment-with-the-Asset-Pipeline). We have followed it and now we no longer need to precompile assets locally and keep in repo.