# My css file is overridden due to activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

First I have created an active_admin css file as `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss`

```
/* active_admin.css.scss */
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";

/* application.css.scss*/
@import "active_admin.css.scss"
```

So I have a lot of css of mine been overriden, I followed instructions of [this post](http://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2011/rails-fix-activeadmin-css-over-riding-problem) but still doesn't work. 
I changed files location from `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` to 
`vendor/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` but still having the problem.

So, how can I load activeadmin css files only when needed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For active_admin to play nice don't include it in the application.css, i.e.: remove the

```
require_tree .
```

and require each file separately inside app/assets/stylesheets
but don't put active_admin.css

and on config/production.rb put this

```
config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.css']
```

Comment: this line will make the active admin css available to admin section --> config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.css']

Comment: you have to list/put all the CSS name there inside application.css except active_admin.css and remove --> require_tree

Comment: Two things:
1. Adding active_admin.css to the precompile list isn't necessary; AA already does that.
2. There's an open ticket to deal with the problem described here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2514

Answer (score 80):

Based on seanlinsley comment on selected answer and nathan's answer too,
it seems to me that the 'cleanest' way is indeed to move `active_admin.css.scss` from `app/assets/stylesheets/` to `vendor/assets/stylesheets/`.

No need to any other (configuration) modification: 'main' app has it's styles back to normal and AA display is normal too.

(I didn't want to manually include each of my ressources instead of require_tree ... !)

This is the way AA is getting into: [AA (still) opened issue on the matter](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2514).

Comment: Simplest solution is always the best :-) am curious to know more of how this works though? will look into vendor assets more and how they are compiled

Comment: @Richlewis I am interested in your findings: to my knowledge, vendor assets are traditionally "installed" by gems so my "solution" is more of a hack (but still the "cleanest" in my point of view). Please feel free to comment if I'm mistaken...)

Comment: Just for record, this solution **doesn't** work for **Rails 2.2**

Comment: This worked for me on Rails 6.1.4

Comment: Yup, it worked for me as well. **Rails 7**

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me (Rails 5) was adding the following line on my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css after the `*= require_self` line:

```
*= stub "active_admin"
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line from your app/assets/stylehseets/application.css.sass

```
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/
```

Move active_admin.css.scss to vendor/assets/stylesheets/

Answer (score 2):

This is the link that addresses this issue. I am reposting an existing answer that I found very helpful because it also addressed the js issues. Again Not My Answer.

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3819#issuecomment-351377822

> arif362 commented on Dec 13, 2017

the same problem I faced and I have solved this following below:

Firstly you have to create a directory named assets in the vendor directory,

Then in the assets directory of vendor folder, you have to create two directories (i) stylesheets and the second one is (ii) javascripts.

After that, you have to move the active_admin.scss file from `assets/stylesheets` to `vendor/assets/stylesheets` and the `active_admin.js.coffee` file from `assets/javascripts` to `vendor/assets/javascripts`,

And finally, restart your rails server then reload your apps. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This post is pretty old, so I figured including my recent findings with an updated version of Rails (6.1.4) was worth it.

Moving `active_admin.css.scss` from `app/assets/stylesheets/` to `vendor/assets/stylesheets/` worked for me too.

Using Rails `6.1.4`

Comment: Good to know @sandypockets !
If I'm not mistaken, this is the option I suggested. If so, could you please say so in a comment in my solution for later visitors to know that it's a viable solution. Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your solution. But I did upvote it before leaving my own comment as an answer. But your solution is definitely what guided me that way, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Previously I used bootstrap styling in my rails application, then all stylings are changed into `scss` due to active admin. I did all the things specified above, but it won't worked for me. I changed this line in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

into

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag %>
```

It was worked for me