# Foundation 5 - Rails 4 css topbar not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am having an issue with foundation 5, rails 4.1.0, as per screenshot, links are underlined, search box is off.
I have created a separate dummy rails app with the same spec and don't see the same issue
I've tried without turbolinks, and different topbar configurations.
any ideas where to troubleshoot this?

Screenshot:
http://postimg.org/image/ohtwc60rj/

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
$(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
});
`
```

application.css.scss

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'foundation-rails'

gem 'rails_12factor'

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'


group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  #gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'slop'
  gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
  gem 'jazz_hands'
end

gem 'pg', '0.17.1'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'guard-spork', :github => 'guard/guard-spork'
  gem 'spork', :github => 'sporkrb/spork'
end

#Server monitoring
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
```

Comment: Found that active admin was conflicting. commented out active_admin.css.scss resolved the issue. That put me in the right direction. Can't close my question, mod please close

Comment: Fix from Foundation when using active admin
http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1359-foundation-5-impacted-by-active-admin-on-rails-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that active admin was conflicting. commented out active_admin.css.scss resolved the issue. That put me in the right direction
Fix from Foundation when using active admin http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1359-foundation-5-impacted-by-active-admin-on-rails-4

Comment: what do you mean by "commented out active_admin.css.scss"? Did you comment out the entire file? Or comment out an include somewhere?

Comment: I found a solution in the answer by @gfd in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304681/activeadmin-overides-my-css) .  Essentially, move ```active_admin.scss``` from ```app``` to ```vendor```.