# how to stop an active_admin css.scss file changing the whole look of my application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, activeadmin

I have a ruby on rails project, ruby2 and rails4. I've got the bootstrap-sass gem installed. I recently installed the activeadmin gem, which adds a file active_admin.css.scss to my app/styles folder:

```
// SASS variable overrides must be declared before loading up Active Admin's styles.
//
// To view the variables that Active Admin provides, take a look at
// `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss` in the
// Active Admin source.
//
// For example, to change the sidebar width:
// $sidebar-width: 242px;

// Active Admin's got SASS!
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";

// Overriding any non-variable SASS must be done after the fact.
// For example, to change the default status-tag color:
//
//   .status_tag { background: #6090DB; }
```

Now the buttons and forms throughout my project, which I've designed with bootstrap class, look all different. It's like the active_admin.css.scss is over-riding my whole project. When I comment out the below lines like so:

```
   // @import "active_admin/mixins";
   // @import "active_admin/base";
```

My original buttons return, but ActiveAdmin is a mess to look at.Any idea how I can sort out this problem - just have active_admin.css.scss deal with my actice_admin stuff, and leave the rest alone?

Comment: do you have firebug installed? check which class is overwritten, then you need to update them,

Comment: don't have firebug installed, I use Chrome. I can see 'color: #38678b;
text-decoration: underline;', classes I don't want to use - it's changed the colour and decoration of my links, but don't how to change these, as they're not explicitly defined in css.scss files. Must be taken from the active_admin gem file.

Comment: then it must be written in .js file search and update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a trail of research started by James Chen below (and thanks to Ryan Bates!) I found this video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Towards the end of the video, it fixes my problem. Wouldn't mind, but I watched the first part of the video several days ago to get the active_admin gem installed, and then stopped watching.

Basically, if you have sass installed, change your application.css file to application.css.scss, and some other small bits and bobs.

Answer (score 6):

Usually admin area has its own layout and assets (javascripts and stylesheets). I doubt there's any need to include active_admin assets in your app's none admin pages.

If your application.css includes all stylesheets by default with this:

`*= require_true .`

Then copying 3rd-party assets into assets folder will break your style as you describe. Consider changing it to include stylesheets explicitly or using the methods described in this article:

http://mrdanadams.com/2011/exclude-active-admin-js-css-rails/

The article is 3 years old so it's possible parts of it have to be changed, but the idea is there.

Comment: I didn't include it by choice - it just put the scss file in there, when I did gem install active_admin.

Comment: Well in this case I guess your application.css includes all css under the folder by default (`*= require_true .`). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Elegant solution! And enlgihtened me about `require_tree` too!

Answer (score 4):

A better solution that works for Rails 4 is to move active_admin css and javascript files to /vendor. To load the assets correctly in production, add the following lines to `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += 
%w( #{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)
config.assets.precompile += 
%w( #{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee)
```

I found the fix in this [issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/825).

Comment: Thanks. Be sure to run assets using RAILS_ENV: rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production if you are pushing your assets on heroku/server

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to James Chen and the link to Dan Adam's blog.  I decided to consolidate the two articles into this answer. The following steps should resolve the problem on Rails 4.0:

1 - Ensure that your Active Admin assets are not in the root folders which are applied to the whole application:

```
cd app/assets/javascripts
mkdir admin
mv active_admin.js.coffee admin/

cd ../stylesheets
mkdir admin
mv active_admin.css.scss admin/
```

2 - And actually, make sure that the assets are not included, via editing both files
`assets/stylesheets/application.css` and `assets/javascripts/application.js`
change `require_tree .` to `require_directory .`

3 - Now you need to change your Active Admin initializer to grab the two files you just excluded in steps 1 and 2:
In file `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` add the following lines:

```
config.clear_stylesheets!
config.register_stylesheet 'admin/active_admin.css'

config.clear_javascripts!
config.register_javascript 'admin/active_admin.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Karen
  pointed out in this answer [Rails Active Admin css conflicting with Twitter Bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180418/rails-active-admin-css-conflicting-with-twitter-bootstrap-css), you could just move the stylesheet `active_admin.css.scss` from `app/assets/stylesheets` to `vendor/assets/stylesheets`